# Does anyone know of how I would authenticate the data my algorithm generates?

Tags: database

I have a pytorch model that generates bond trade pairs that have a high probability of reverting to the mean in a 30 day time period.

I want to sell the signals, but I do not want them to be redistributed. Is there a way to encrypt my data signals, if I put them on a marketplace like Amazon Data Exchange or Snowflake?

Comment: It's unclear to me what "signals" are relative to designation of "bond trade pairs". If they are synonymous, and basically reduce to pairs of ticker symbols for a given period, I don't see that cryptography can provide a technical protection against several potential customers conspiring to share the intel you sell to one. Protection has to be on the tune of an exhortation: do not share or I'll sue/you'll loose your self esteem|&money/you'll end up in jail|hell.

Comment: No. Anyone who can read the signals can just tell another person what the signals were. But you can make them sign a contract saying they won't, and then, you can sue them.

Comment: And if your model really is that good, why would you sell the signals? You should rather trade on the signals yourself, and you could be a billionaire this time next year. Go on, what are you waiting for?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to give some data to someone and then prevent them giving the data to another person.

For example, they could just memorize what your algorithm says, then tell it to their friend. Or they could take a photo of their computer screen.

The MPAA once tried to solve this by making cameras illegal. It didn't work. Cameras are still not illegal.